# Software KVM for OS X & Windows

Tags: macos, windows, kvm

I have a Dell 27″ monitor with the DVI input connected to my Windows machine and the DisplayPort connected to my MacBook Air. I can change the input manually but it's fairly tedious.

I'm looking for a software KVM that works on both. I've found [ShareMouse](http://www.share-mouse.com/) and [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) which do the KM part very nicely. There's [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) which only works on Windows machines which also can switch monitors using [DDC/CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) (haven't tried this yet). Would anyone know of something that switches all of KVM in software? Like ShareMouse does but with the monitor as well and runs on Windows and OS X.

I have a couple of other monitors connected to the PC so could perhaps use input director on the windows box and switch somehow but seems a bit messy.

Comment: mControl from here http://www.entechtaiwan.com/ runs on windows and provides a part solution along with a KM. It means I have to move my taskbar off the main monitor, otherwise I can't switch inputs back to windows in software, but probably does the job. A more integrated solution would be nice